# Creating a flood from a seed point in an array

Tags: python, numpy

I have created a python script that takes a 2D NumPy array of elevation values and given a seed value and an elevation it will grow a flood from that seed point. It does this by checking all adjacent cells to see if they are above or below the flood level. From there it checks all of those locations until all cells that touch a flooded cell have been checked. If a cell is below the flood level, but surrounded by higher values it doesn't get flooded.

This is the test code. I then implement it in GIS where I convert a raster to an array and process that. This works, but doesn't scale well at all if used with a larger raster, i.e. takes ages.

How can I improve this code, is this the right approach in python? I know there are GIS tools to do this out there, this is a learning task for myself.

```
''' 
This program is designed to generate in_array flood array from in_array seed point 
    and an elevation to flood to. The output array is set to 0 where 
    the cell is calculated to be flooded and retains its elevation 
    everywhere else.
'''

#Support Python 3 print functionality in Python 2
from __future__ import print_function

#import generic modules
import sys
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#global variables
in_array = np.random.rand(0)
proc_array = np.random.rand(0)
spent = []
to_process = []

''' 
Main calling block 
'''
def proc_main():
    print('Starting...')
    try:
        #Run actual functionality
        proc_run()
    except Exception as e:
        print ('Error:' + str(e))
    finally:
        pass
        #optional wait for keypress
        #input('Press Enter...')

''' 
Main program functionality
'''  
def proc_run():
    global in_array,proc_array, spent, to_process
    #in_array = np.random.rand(11,11)
    in_array = np.array([[5,9,5,5,5,5,9,5,5,5,5],
                  [5,9,5,5,9,9,9,5,5,5,5],
                  [9,9,5,5,9,5,9,5,5,5,5],
                  [9,9,5,5,9,9,9,5,5,5,5],
                  [5,5,5,5,5,5,9,5,5,5,9],
                  [5,5,5,5,5,8,9,5,5,5,9],
                  [5,5,5,5,5,5,9,5,5,5,9],
                  [5,5,5,5,5,5,9,5,5,5,5],
                  [5,5,5,5,5,5,9,5,5,5,5],
                  [5,5,5,5,5,5,9,5,5,5,5],
                  [5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5]])
    #plot array
    plt.imshow(in_array, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
    plt.colorbar()
    plt.show()
    #set sed location
    loc = [5,5]
    to_process.append(loc)
    #water
    flood_z = 8.5
    #make in_array copy of array for processing
    proc_array = np.copy(in_array)
    #check if origin can flood
    if in_array[loc[0], loc[1]] <= flood_z:
        proc_array[loc[0], loc[1]] = -9999
        #process seed
        proc_loc(loc, flood_z)
        #process whole array
        for i in to_process:
            if proc_array[i[0],i[1]] == -9999:
                proc_loc(i, flood_z)
                to_process.remove(i)  
                spent.append(i) 
    else:
        print('Seed location is above flood value given')
        raise
    #classify array and mask input array    
    proc_array[proc_array > -9999] = 1       
    proc_array[proc_array <= -9999] = 0
    out_array = in_array * proc_array
    #plot mask and new array
    plt.imshow(proc_array, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
    plt.show()
    plt.imshow(out_array, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
    plt.colorbar()
    plt.show()


'''
Takes an array location and an elevation and looks at the 8 surrounding
    cells to see if they are below the elevation.
'''            
def proc_loc(loc, flood_z):
    global proc_array, spent
    if loc not in spent:
        rows, cols = in_array.shape
        rownum = loc[0]
        colnum = loc[1]
        if rownum - 1 != -1:
            # -1 -1 top left
            if colnum - 1 != -1:
                proc_array[rownum - 1, colnum - 1] = \
                    cal_z([rownum - 1, colnum - 1],
                          proc_array[rownum - 1, colnum - 1], flood_z)
            #-1 0 top
            proc_array[rownum - 1, colnum] = \
                cal_z([rownum - 1, colnum],
                          proc_array[rownum - 1, colnum], flood_z)
            #-1 +1 top right
            if colnum + 1 < int(cols):
                proc_array[rownum - 1, colnum + 1] = \
                    cal_z([rownum - 1, colnum + 1],
                          proc_array[rownum - 1, colnum + 1], flood_z)
        if colnum - 1 != -1:
            #0 -1 left
            proc_array[rownum, colnum - 1] = \
                cal_z([rownum, colnum -1],
                          proc_array[rownum, colnum - 1], flood_z)
            if colnum + 1 < int(cols):
                #right
                proc_array[rownum, colnum + 1] = \
                    cal_z([rownum, colnum +1],
                          proc_array[rownum, colnum + 1], flood_z)
        if rownum + 1 < int(rows):
            #+1 -1 bottom left
            if colnum - 1 != -1:
                proc_array[rownum + 1, colnum - 1] = \
                    cal_z([rownum + 1, colnum - 1],
                          proc_array[rownum + 1, colnum - 1], flood_z)
            #+1 0 bottom
            proc_array[rownum + 1, colnum] = \
                cal_z([rownum + 1, colnum],
                          proc_array[rownum + 1, colnum], flood_z)
            #+1 +1 bottom right                
            if colnum + 1 < int(cols):
                proc_array[rownum + 1, colnum + 1] = \
                    cal_z([rownum + 1, colnum + 1],
                          proc_array[rownum + 1, colnum + 1], flood_z)
'''
Takes an array location in_array flood_z value and the target elevation and checks if
    the flood_z value s below the target. If it is the array location is
    added to the list to be processed.
'''                   
def cal_z(loc, cell_z, flood_z):
    global to_process
    to_process.append(loc)
    if cell_z <= flood_z:
        return -9999
    else:
        return 9999

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Support Python 2 and 3 input
    # If this is Python 2, use raw_input()
    if sys.version_info[0] >= 3:
        input = input
        range = range
    else:
        input = raw_input
        range = xrange

    #run main program
    proc_main()
```

Comment: This 'flooding' technique is one often used in computer vision under the name of computing a 'watershed'. I'd suggest looking into implementations of this algorithm in imaging libraries, such as [this](http://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.morphology.html#watershed). If applicable, it'll likely make your code faster and easier to read.

Comment: I was unaware of that, thanks. However, after an interesting morning looking into this I don't believe it is the same functionality as I'm after. Watershed finds borders between basins, not connected cells or islands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a job for [`scipy.ndimage.measurements.label`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.measurements.label.html#scipy.ndimage.measurements.label). Suppose that we have an array of elevations:

```
elevation = np.array([[5,9,5,5,5,5,9,5,5,5,5],
                      [5,9,5,5,9,9,9,5,5,5,5],
                      [9,9,5,5,9,5,9,5,5,5,5],
                      [9,9,5,5,9,9,9,5,5,5,5],
                      [5,5,5,5,5,5,9,5,5,5,9],
                      [5,5,5,5,5,8,9,5,5,5,9],
                      [5,5,5,5,5,5,9,5,5,5,9],
                      [5,5,5,5,5,5,9,5,5,5,5],
                      [5,5,5,5,5,5,9,5,5,5,5],
                      [5,5,5,5,5,5,9,5,5,5,5],
                      [5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5]])
```

together with a flood level and a seed point for the flood:

```
flood_level = 8.5
flood_seed = 5, 5
```

Then `elevation < flood_level` is an array containing `True` for each cell that is below the flood level, and `False` otherwise. Passing this array to `scipy.ndimage.measurements.label` gives an array labelling the orthogonally connected regions, together with the count of the regions:

```
regions, nregions = scipy.ndimage.measurements.label(elevation < flood_level)
```

Here `regions` is the array:

```
[[1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2],
 [1, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2],
 [0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 3, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2],
 [0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2],
 [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0],
 [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0],
 [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0],
 [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2],
 [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2],
 [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2],
 [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]]
```

Each labelled region corresponds to a floodable basin in the original problem, and `regions[flood_seed]` gives the number of the region that is flooded starting at `flood_seed`: here, region 2.